# ECS - Images using localhost

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have services, one for frontend and one for backend.

I have created 2 images for these services and I would like to deploy them on AWS ECS. Currently, the frontend service communicate with the backend with localhost since it was used locally.

Will it cause issues if I deploy it on AWS on 2 different tasks/instances?

Or is it a way to somehow route localhost from the frontend container to the backend server?

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy the services on 2 different tasks/instances, they could not communicate using localhost. Consider using ECS Service Discovery to manage HTTP and DNS namespaces for your Amazon ECS services, you could refer to the following tutorials:

[1] Tutorial: Creating an Amazon ECS Service That Uses Service Discovery Using the Amazon ECS CLI  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-servicediscovery.html

[2] https://ecsworkshop.com/microservices/

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would a load balancer do the trick as well?

Comment: Thanks for that. Now suppose I don't want to use any of these services because they are paid services, can I configure communication by myself? I mean is there an option to configure it so it will be free?

Comment: ELB can do the trick, where you configure a stable service endpoint that your applications can connect to.  However, it is more efficient to have direct communication with a given ECS task, ECS service discovery may be a better approach than using load balancers.

Comment: you could also consider running both containers in the same task, so that one container references the other on a localhost port.

Comment: I tried that but I don't want to have them both on the same task so it will be more flexible and scalable. I am looking into setting it up manually with a VPC and security group. Will it be enough to have such communication?